# Can't npm install in azure with pipeline and outside library hosted in azure artifacts

Tags: angular, azure, npm, devops, azure-artifacts

I'm a little struggled with doing the deploy of my application in Azure. I'm trying several times to do an npm install but it's hard failing. This is due an own Angular library hosted in Azure artifacts.

Why is the library a problem? Because if I do an npm install without authenticate to my artifacts registry, this fails because the library isn't in the public npm registry and if I put the .npmrc with the registry where my library is hosted, "npm install" fails because it can't reach the packages hosted in npm.

Maybe I'm missing something. So I'm going to tell you most of the things that I'm doing because I have never done something like this (Create an Angular library, host in artifcats, use it on my application and then deploy it on azure)

First I created the library, once coded I have builded and the dist looks like this.

[image: Library]

in my npmrc used to connect to the artifact registry and publish this package I have this

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/

always-auth=true
```

and in my root package.json I have this. I don't know if in my package I need something more to make it work, but until this moment I have been able to download this library in my app and use it in local

```
{
  "name": "mm-core",
  "version": "0.0.34",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.5"
  },
  "main": "bundles/mm-core-utils.umd.js",
  "module": "fesm5/mm-core-utils.js",
  "es2015": "fesm2015/mm-core-utils.js",
  "esm5": "esm5/mm-core-utils.js",
  "esm2015": "esm2015/mm-core-utils.js",
  "fesm5": "fesm5/mm-core-utils.js",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/mm-core-utils.js",
  "typings": "mm-core-utils.d.ts",
  "metadata": "mm-core-utils.metadata.json",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

In my application I have added the same .npmrc on the root to have access to my library, and this are my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.5",
    "@nrwl/angular": "9.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "mm-core": "0.0.37",
    "rfs": "^9.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.0",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "9.0.1",
    "@nrwl/jest": "9.0.1",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "9.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.9",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~5.0.1",
    "cypress": "^3.8.2",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "eslint": "6.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.0.0",
    "mm-core": "0.0.32",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.4"
  }
```

Until this moment, that has worked good. I have been able to download the packages through the public npm registry and then authenticate on my azure artifacts to download the library "mm-core"

But when I try to run the pipeline, all of this explodes.

[image]

Npm install failed with return code 1

```
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2263247Z ##[section]Starting: npm Install
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2371772Z ==============================================================================
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2372090Z Task         : npm
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2372483Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2372887Z Version      : 1.164.0
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2373117Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2373443Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
2020-03-09T07:51:11.2373822Z ==============================================================================
2020-03-09T07:51:11.6568682Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2020-03-09T07:51:11.8936693Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2020-03-09T07:51:13.1888912Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\12.16.1\x64\npm.cmd --version"
2020-03-09T07:51:13.6882590Z 6.13.4
2020-03-09T07:51:13.6961961Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2020-03-09T07:51:13.7440810Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2020-03-09T07:51:14.7302010Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\12.16.1\x64\npm.cmd config list"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2125337Z ; cli configs
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2125983Z metrics-registry = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2126377Z scope = ""
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2126642Z user-agent = "npm/6.13.4 node/v12.16.1 win32 x64"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2126869Z 
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2127086Z ; environment configs
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2127336Z cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2127572Z loglevel = "verbose"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2127820Z prefix = "C:\\npm\\prefix"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2128091Z userconfig = "d:\\a\\1\\npm\\3607.npmrc"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2128304Z 
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2128522Z ; project config d:\a\1\s\.npmrc
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2128779Z always-auth = true
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2129150Z registry = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2129612Z 
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2129911Z ; node bin location = C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\12.16.1\x64\node.exe
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2130214Z ; cwd = d:\a\1\s
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2130458Z ; HOME = C:\Users\VssAdministrator
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2130747Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2130956Z 
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2131938Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\12.16.1\x64\npm.cmd install"
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2133029Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2133274Z npm verb cli [
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2133575Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node.exe',
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2134002Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2134367Z npm verb cli   'prefix',
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2134606Z npm verb cli   '-g'
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2134819Z npm verb cli ]
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2135052Z npm info using npm@6.13.4
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2135295Z npm info using node@v12.16.1
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2135537Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2135796Z npm timing npm Completed in 47ms
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2136021Z npm info ok 
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2136256Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2136503Z npm verb cli [
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2136804Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node.exe',
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2137232Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2137589Z npm verb cli   'config',
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2137817Z npm verb cli   'list'
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2138031Z npm verb cli ]
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2138263Z npm info using npm@6.13.4
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2138500Z npm info using node@v12.16.1
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2139632Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2139899Z npm timing npm Completed in 31ms
2020-03-09T07:51:15.2140131Z npm info ok 
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6186646Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6186968Z npm verb cli [
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6187190Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node.exe',
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6187536Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6187821Z npm verb cli   'prefix',
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6187966Z npm verb cli   '-g'
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6188097Z npm verb cli ]
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6188254Z npm info using npm@6.13.4
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6188410Z npm info using node@v12.16.1
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6188565Z npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6188729Z npm timing npm Completed in 47ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6188893Z npm info ok 
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6189065Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6189219Z npm verb cli [
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6189485Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node.exe',
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6189826Z npm verb cli   'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6190089Z npm verb cli   'install'
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6190239Z npm verb cli ]
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6190376Z npm info using npm@6.13.4
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6190531Z npm info using node@v12.16.1
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6190710Z npm verb npm-session 17470d0c5f840511
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6190980Z npm info lifecycle mallmark-wallet@0.0.0~preinstall: mallmark-wallet@0.0.0
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6191257Z npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 16ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6191681Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6192162Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1313ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6192463Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 1801ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6192741Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 3723ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6193148Z npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 908ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6193437Z npm verb correctMkdir C:\npm\cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6193716Z npm verb makeCacheDir UID & GID are irrelevant on win32
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6194063Z npm verb lock using C:\npm\cache\_locks\staging-7a8d0a4441b61671.lock for d:\a\1\s\node_modules\.staging
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6194510Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/core-js 1266ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6194981Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/core-js 110ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6195339Z npm timing action:extract Completed in 1485ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6195723Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/common/-/common-9.0.5.tgz 1549ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6196247Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@babel%2fparser 1315ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6196746Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/path-exists 1580ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6197226Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/fs-minipass 1518ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6197728Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/core/-/core-9.0.5.tgz 1471ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6198241Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/yallist 1596ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6198742Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/forms/-/forms-9.0.5.tgz 218ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6199730Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/typescript 1580ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6200242Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/compiler/-/compiler-9.0.5.tgz 187ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6200843Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@babel%2fplugin-transform-for-of 1158ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6201424Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/platform-browser/-/platform-browser-9.0.5.tgz 250ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6201959Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/path-exists 125ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6202439Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/rfs 423ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6202917Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@nrwl%2fworkspace 219ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6203422Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/core-js/-/core-js-3.6.4.tgz 377ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6203940Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/fs-minipass 110ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6204415Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/typescript 110ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6204893Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/tslint 501ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6205363Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/minipass 1736ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6205906Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@babel%2fplugin-transform-for-of 93ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6206452Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/router/-/router-9.0.5.tgz 390ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6206954Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/codelyzer 424ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6207426Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/typescript 518ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6207916Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@types%2fjest 282ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6208407Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular%2fcli 188ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6208919Z npm http fetch POST 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 1972ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6209440Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/caniuse-lite 1815ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6209914Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/cypress 485ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6210388Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/rfs 109ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6210859Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@nrwl%2fworkspace 62ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6211389Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@babel%2fparser 250ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6211881Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/tslint 30ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6212340Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/jest 485ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6212811Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/ts-node 548ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6213292Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/jest-preset-angular 533ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6213771Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/minipass 46ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6214251Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/make-dir 1784ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6214725Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/typescript 46ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6215224Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/mm-core/-/mm-core-0.0.37.tgz 549ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6215736Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/caniuse-lite 32ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6216220Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/jest-preset-angular 47ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6216791Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/animations/-/animations-9.0.5.tgz 297ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6217351Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular%2fcompiler-cli 454ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6217865Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/jest 63ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6757795Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/codelyzer 109ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6758407Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/yallist 281ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6759000Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular 234ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6759605Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular%2fcompiler-cli 15ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6760909Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular 63ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6761507Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/cypress 172ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6762284Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@nrwl%2fangular 453ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6762879Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/ts-node 172ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6763523Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular%2flanguage-service 594ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6764163Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@nrwl%2fangular 32ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6764988Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/-/platform-browser-dynamic-9.0.5.tgz 610ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6765760Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular%2flanguage-service 31ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6766415Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/prettier 814ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6767028Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@types%2fjest 327ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6767661Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/bootstrap 735ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6768277Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/dotenv 814ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6768886Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/make-dir 297ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6769520Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/@angular%2fcli 343ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6770206Z npm verb unlock done using C:\npm\cache\_locks\staging-7a8d0a4441b61671.lock for d:\a\1\s\node_modules\.staging
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6770771Z npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6771176Z npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 7603ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6771613Z npm WARN The package mm-core is included as both a dev and production dependency.
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6771879Z 
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6772393Z npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/core-js - NotFound
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6773636Z npm verb stack     at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\12.16.1\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6774625Z npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6774936Z npm verb statusCode 404
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6775131Z npm verb pkgid core-js@3.6.0
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6775359Z npm verb cwd d:\a\1\s
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6775579Z npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.14393
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6776133Z npm verb argv "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node.exe" "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6776612Z npm verb node v12.16.1
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6776857Z npm verb npm  v6.13.4
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6777070Z npm ERR! code E404
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6777540Z npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/core-js - NotFound
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6778028Z npm ERR! 404 
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6778256Z npm ERR! 404  'core-js@3.6.0' is not in the npm registry.
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6778634Z npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6779063Z npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@angular-devkit/build-angular'
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6779328Z npm ERR! 404 
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6779549Z npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6779868Z npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6780115Z npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6780574Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/eslint 1706ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6781194Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/prettier 908ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6781883Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/bootstrap 892ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6783117Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/dotenv 892ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6783739Z npm http fetch GET 404 https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/eslint 78ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6784169Z npm timing npm Completed in 8934ms
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6784327Z 
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6784527Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6784853Z npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2020-03-09T07_51_24_442Z-debug.log
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6788355Z Found npm debug log, make sure the path matches with the one in npm's output: C:\npm\cache\_logs\2020-03-09T07_51_24_442Z-debug.log
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6788787Z 8004 silly decomposeActions build merge-descriptors@1.0.1
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6789078Z 8005 silly decomposeActions install merge-descriptors@1.0.1
2020-03-09T07:51:24.6789375Z 8006 silly decomposeActions postinstall merge-descriptors@1.0.1
(...)
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0081551Z 17622 silly saveTree +-- ts-jest@24.0.0
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0081741Z 17622 silly saveTree +-- ts-node@7.0.1
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0081932Z 17622 silly saveTree | +-- arrify@1.0.1
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0082133Z 17622 silly saveTree | +-- diff@3.5.0
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0082316Z 17622 silly saveTree | `-- yn@2.0.0
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0082505Z 17622 silly saveTree +-- tslint@5.11.0
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0082723Z 17622 silly saveTree | +-- builtin-modules@1.1.1
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0082931Z 17622 silly saveTree | `-- tsutils@2.29.0
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0083129Z 17622 silly saveTree +-- typescript@3.7.5
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0083322Z 17622 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.10.2
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0083586Z 17623 warn The package mm-core is included as both a dev and production dependency.
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0084031Z 17624 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/core-js - NotFound
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0084612Z 17624 verbose stack     at C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\12.16.1\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0085092Z 17624 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0085347Z 17625 verbose statusCode 404
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0085517Z 17626 verbose pkgid core-js@3.6.0
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0085701Z 17627 verbose cwd d:\a\1\s
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0085879Z 17628 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0086288Z 17629 verbose argv "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node.exe" "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\12.16.1\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0086690Z 17630 verbose node v12.16.1
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0086851Z 17631 verbose npm  v6.13.4
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0087003Z 17632 error code E404
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0087366Z 17633 error 404 Not Found - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_packaging/mallmark-core/npm/registry/core-js - NotFound
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0087698Z 17634 error 404
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0087885Z 17635 error 404 'core-js@3.6.0' is not in the npm registry.
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0088166Z 17636 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0088489Z 17637 error 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@angular-devkit/build-angular'
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0088760Z 17638 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0088993Z 17639 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0089206Z 17640 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0089322Z 
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0114592Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2020-03-09T07:51:25.0129942Z ##[section]Finishing: npm Install
```

I don't have a clue about what's happening and why is telling me that a package from npm is not in the registry when artifacts uses the public npm registry too.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I have solved a part of this problem. I couldn't fetch well the packages because I had a project trying to reach to the artifacts of another project, so my pipeline was scoped only to the project without the artifacts.

But then, I encountered another problem. Npm install is failing now due a dependency of other package.

```
"4604 verbose stack minimist: No matching version found for minimist@^1.2.0.
4604 verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:122:13)
4604 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:24:14
4604 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
4604 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
4604 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
4604 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:611:10)
4604 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:142:12)
4604 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
4604 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
4604 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
4604 verbose stack     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
"
```

In azure artifacts I have the minimist version of 1.1.3. Artifacts should auto search in the public upstreams if in the local/private registry this package version isn't exist right?

I have encountered this ticket that is a lot of similar to my problem:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/420204/azure-devops-artifact-upstream-source-npm-not-work-1.html

But the solution isn't working for me. In my package.json I'm intalling this version of minimist (1.2.0) then publish the package with a new version but the version of minimist isn't updating, remains in 1.1.3. However if I try to do this with @angular/animations, update the version from 9.0.0 to 9.0.5, it works

Comment: You can specify the latest version in the `Node.js tool installer` task and try `13.x`.In addition ,do you run [vsts-npm-auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OKSG.png) to get an Artifacts token added to your user-level .npmrc file?

Comment: I have update the question with a part solution. But now there is another problem